# Inserting Formula ONLY visible Cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have data in 3 Columns

A B & C, in which a Filter is active on column A, I want to apply a code so that the formula is applied on Column C - from the 2nd visible row till the last visible row.

Here is the code I have written, However It doesn't work if I change the Range("C:C") or Range("C2:C")

```
Sub Test()
Dim rng As Range 

Range("C1").Select

Set rng = Application.Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("**C2:C2000**"))

rng.Select

Selection.Formula = "=RC[-1]+RC[-2]"

End Sub
```

Comment: Look into [specialcells() function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

With an active [AutoFilter method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221844.aspx), presumably your first row contains column header labels and the data is below that. The [Range.CurrentRegion property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678.aspx) is a better fit for this situation than the [Worksheet.UsedRange property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840732.aspx).

The [Range.SpecialCells method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) with [xlCellTypeVisible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836534.aspx) will reference the visible cells. I find that the worksheet's [SUBTOTAL function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUBTOTAL-function-e27c301c-be9a-458b-9d12-b9a2ce3c62af) provides a nice non-destructive method of seeing iof there are visible cells before trying to access them.

A few [With ... End With statements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) will help you progressively isolate the cells you are looking for.

```
Sub test()
    'note that not a single var is necessary

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")   '<~~ surely you know what worksheet you are on
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0) '<~~one row down
                If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
                    'there are visible cells
                    With .Columns(3).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                        .Cells.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]+RC[-2]"
                    End With
                End If
            End With
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

I've used the [Range.FormulaR1C1 property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb213527(v=office.12).aspx) (as opposed to your original [Range.Formula property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838835.aspx)) single you were using `xlR1C1` not `xlA1` formula syntax.

Comment: Hi Jeeped, Thanks very much for the quick response.