# Apply formula with VBA using dynamic cell references.

Tags: vba, excel, loops, excel-formula

Hi I am trying to apply a formula to a range of cells based on a condition. However if I loop through the cells applying the formula then it applies it without dynamic cell referencing. (like as if I'd try to drag the formula down manually by clicking on the bottom right corner of the initial cell). How would I go about making the cell references in the applied formula dynamic? Any help would be appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
Sub OQWDays()
Dim oqs As Worksheet

Set oqs = Sheets("SQL_IMPORT")

    For x = 2 To oqs.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        If oqs.Range("J" & x).Value = ("CBN_Suisse") Then oqs.Range("A" & x).Formula = "=NETWORKDAYS(D2,PUBLIC_HOLIDAYS!$G$3,PUBLIC_HOLIDAYS!$E$44:$E$61)"

    Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: so you want `D2` to change to `Dx` where x is the row number?

Comment: replace `D2,` with `D" & x & ",`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* you mean this. Take the 2 out of the string and replace with x?

```
Sub OQWDays()

Dim oqs As Worksheet

Set oqs = Sheets("SQL_IMPORT")

For x = 2 To oqs.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    If oqs.Range("J" & x).Value = "CBN_Suisse" Then
        oqs.Range("A" & x).Formula = "=NETWORKDAYS(D" & x & ",PUBLIC_HOLIDAYS!$G$3,PUBLIC_HOLIDAYS!$E$44:$E$61)"
    End If
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, Scott Craner posted the same solution and it worked great, so thank you guys.

Comment: Glad it worked. You might also want to consider using AutoFilter to avoid looping, particularly if you have lots of rows.

Comment: Just curious, how would you run this procedure without a Loop and with an AutoFilter? Can you show me or point me to a guide/tutorial that explains it? I've not heard of the AutoFilter ways.

Comment: Your best bet is honestly to google and/or consult VBA help. There are plenty of examples of how to filter data, eg see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35210193/inserting-formula-only-visible-cells